# Fetch all user ids under domain

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-admin-sdk

How do I fetch all user Ids under our company domain using Google API?

I want to get list of all users under our domain.

Then I want to get a list of all emails for each user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to [**Retrieve all users in a domain**](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_domain_users):

> To retrieve all users in the same domain, use the following `GET` request and include the authorization described in [Authorize requests](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing.html). For readability, this example uses line returns:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users
?domain=primary domain name&pageToken=token for next results page
&maxResults=max number of results per page
&orderBy=email, givenName, or familyName
&sortOrder=ascending or descending
&query=email, givenName, or familyName:the query's value*
```

By default, the system returns a list of 100 users in the alphabetical order of the user's email address:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users?domain=example.com&maxResults=2
```

A successful response returns an [**HTTP 200 status code**](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). Along with the status code, the response returns 2 user accounts in the example.com domain (**`maxResults=2`**):

```
{
 "kind": "directory#users",
 "users": [
  {
   "kind": "directory#user",
   "id": "the unique user id",
   "primaryEmail": "liz@example.com",
   "name": {
    "givenName": "Liz",
    "familyName": "Smith",
    "fullName": "Liz Smith"
   },
   "isAdmin": true,
   "isDelegatedAdmin": false,
   "lastLoginTime": "2013-02-05T10:30:03.325Z",
   "creationTime": "2010-04-05T17:30:04.325Z",
   "agreedToTerms": true,
   "hashFunction: "SHA-1",
   "suspended": false,
   "changePasswordAtNextLogin": false,
   "ipWhitelisted": false,
   "ims": [
    {
     "type": "work",
     "protocol": "gtalk",
     "im": "lizim@talk.example.com",
     "primary": true
    }
   ],
   "emails": [
    {
     "address": "liz@example.com",
     "type": "work",
     "customType": "",
     "primary": true
    }
   ],
   "addresses": [
    {
     "type": "work",
     "customType": "",
     "streetAddress": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
     "locality": "Mountain View",
     "region": "CA",
     "postalCode": "94043"
    }
   ],
   "externalIds": [
    {
     "value": "employee number",
     "type": "custom",
     "customType": "office"
    }
   ],
   "relations": [
    {
     "value": "susan",
     "type": "friend",
     "customType": ""
    }
   ],
   "organizations": [
    {
     "name": "Google Inc.",
     "title": "SWE",
     "primary": true,
     "customType": "",
     "description": "Software engineer"
    }
   ],
   "phones": [
    {
     "value": "+1 nnn nnn nnnn",
     "type": "work"
    }
   ],
   "aliases": [
    "lizsmith@example.com",
    "lsmith@example.com"
   ],
   "nonEditableAliases: [
    "liz@test.com"
   ],
   "customerId": "C03az79cb",
   "orgUnitPath": "corp/engineering",
   "isMailboxSetup": true,
   "includeInGlobalAddressList": true
  },
  {
   "kind": "directory#user",
   "id": "user unique ID",
   "primaryEmail": "admin2@example.com",
   "name": {
    "givenName": "admin",
    "familyName": "two",
    "fullName": "admin two"
   },
   "isAdmin": true,
   "isDelegatedAdmin": true,
   "lastLoginTime": "2013-02-05T10:30:03.325Z",
   "creationTime": "2010-04-05T17:30:04.325Z",
   "agreedToTerms": true,
   "hashFunction: "SHA-1",
   "suspended": true,
   "suspensionReason": "ADMIN",
   "changePasswordAtNextLogin": false,
   "ipWhitelisted": false,
   "emails": [
    {
     "address": "admin2@example.com",
     "type": "work",
     "customType": "",
     "primary": true
    }
   ],
   "externalIds": [
    {
     "value": "contractor license number",
     "type": "custom",
     "customType": "work"
    }
   ],
   "relations": [
    {
     "value": "liz",
     "type": "friend",
     "customType": ""
    }
   ],
   "aliases": [
    "second_admin@example.com"
   ],
   "nonEditableAliases: [
    "admin@test.com"
   ],
   "customerId": "C03az79cb",
   "orgUnitPath": "corp/engineering",
   "isMailboxSetup": true,
   "includeInGlobalAddressList": true
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "next page token"
}
```

You can also check out [Retrieve all account users](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#get_all_users)

> To retrieve all users in an account which can consist of multiple domains, use the following `GET` request and include the authorization described in [**Authorize requests**](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing.html).